# Reasons for invalid synonym

Tags: sql, oracle

In the Oracle docs for ALTER SYNONYM (link below) it says "A synonym places a dependency on its target object and becomes invalid if the target object is changed or dropped."

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2016.htm#SQLRF56347

I have been trying to find the exact scenarios during which this can happen. Is it just when you run ALTER, DROP, or CREATE/REPLACE on a function/table/view, or whatever object the synonym is for? Can an underlying object for a synonym become inaccessible for any other reason?

Also - the result of an invalid synonym is an "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" error, or can it throw others as well?

Assume that the correct grants have been given for everything above please.

Comment: Are you interested in a list of reasons or there is a specific problem you need to solve?

Comment: If you drop a table in your own schema that a synonym points to you can get ORA-00980. Why do you need to know the scenarios it can happen - what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I am asking because I frequently get this "table or view does not exist" error on a particular view. The issue can be resolved by dropping and recreating the synonym, and the only reasons I have found why this would be required is if the object (the view) has been altered, dropped, or replaced. Could there be other reasons?

Comment: Are you sure someone/thing else isn't recreating the synonym pointing somewhat invalid - have you checked that `all_synonyms` looks right, and the same, before you drop and after you recreate? Unless there's a bug in a specific version of Oracle I can't see how the behaviour is possible, otherwise.

Comment: I later found out why this was happening, but I will just make a comment like this as it does not really answer the original question. The synonym that I had to keep recreating was for a materialized view. The way the MV was being refreshed resulted in it not being possible to select the MV using the synonym anymore.